# % change of 2 time period calculations in SQL (GBQ)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, time-series

Currently have multiple calculations similar to this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(A)/COUNT(B) AS CALCULATION
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE YEAR = 2019
```

But I want to find the percent change between Year 2019 and 2018,
like `(Calculation1/Calculation2-1) where calc1 is 2019 and calc2 is 2018`.

Is the best way a temp table or a subquery? What would be some base code to accomplish analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I'm not sure exactly what calculation you want, but something like this:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = 2019 THEN A END) / SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = 2018 THEN A) END) - 1 AS CALCULATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE YEAR IN (2018, 2019)
```

Comment: "No matching signature for function IF for argument types: FLOAT64. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [19:8] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions."

Does BQ not support using time functions in this manner?

Comment: @Harri . . . Just some wishful thinking there.  `sumif()` is supported in Wrangle and I just think it *should* be in BigQuery as well (or better yet, BQ could support the `filter` clause!)

Comment: @Harri . . . As in `count(distinct case when year = 2018 then a end)`?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (SUM(IF(year = 2019, A, 0)) / COUNT(IF(year = 2019, B, NULL))) /
  (SUM(IF(year = 2018, A, 0)) / COUNT(IF(year = 2018, B, NULL))) - 1 AS CALCULATION
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE year IN (2018, 2019)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, is there a way to incorporate a distinct into the COUNT?

Comment: sure. the way SO works is  - you ask question (btw it is important to show your own efforts) - we answer it - you accept/upvote. then if you have new question (like you have now) you ask/post new question  - and it is important to provide all relevant details as well as example of input and expected output

Comment: Got ya - im not able to up vote bc of reputation level on SO. The level of detail has been limited due to the proprietary nature of my data. I appreciate your help.

Comment: sure. you don't need to provide real data - just dummy data to demonstrate your use-case

Comment: Using COUNT(IF(YEAR = '2018',(DISTINCT B), NULL) but its not taking the distinct, ' unexpected keyword', if removed then the division takes my numbers down to zero.

Comment: try `COUNT(DISTINCT IF(year = 2019, B, NULL))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `IF`. A little bit ugly but a more generalized version:

```
with yearlyset as (
  select 
     year, 
     lag(year) over(order by 1) lastyear, 
     coalesce(lag(calculation) over(order by 1), 0) lastyearcalculation, 
     calculation from (
        select year, sum(a)/count(b) as calculation
        from `dataset.table`
        group by 1
     )
)

select 
   year, 
   if(
      year=2019 and lastyear=2018, 
      calculation/lastyearcalculation-1, 
      if(
         coalesce(lastyearcalculation, 0) = 0, 
         0.0, 
         calculation/lastyearcalculation
      ) 
   ) as percent_change
from yearlyset
```